# Get Windows username in Google Chrome with NaCl nexe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, plugins, google-nativeclient

I face the following challenge: How can I retrieve the current logged in user ID in JS with Chrome on Windows?

My current research results are:

- Natively this is not possible
- Active-X is not supported by Chrome
- Most likely it is doable by writing a NaCl nexe Plugin

A I am starting NaCl nexe development at zero knowledge level I would be grateful if someone could provide a template or something like that. Or even better: Perhaps someone who faced the same problem already has written such a plugin and is willing to share his knowledge and code?

Thanks in advance

Michael

Answer (score 0):

If it's not possible in JS, then it isn't possible with NaCl either. NaCl plugins are not allowed to access native system APIs (e.g. win32), in order to protect the user of the browser.

Comment: I thought the system is protected by sandboxing? I may have understood other posts for other questions in this ares wrong but I had the feeling that you can access the Windows API and just have to install the plugin to allow it communicate with the JS core.